# How to prevent to execute tasks which are waiting in executor queue for free thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I got many operations to do on multiple threads.

It should be allowed to pause calculations and increase/decrease thread amount then unpause calculations.

At this moment I can just increase amount of threads - tasks already produced by Future and waiting in queue are processed all time and according to docs threads cannot be reduced:

> public void setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize)
>
> Sets the core number of threads. This overrides any value set in the
>   constructor. **If the new value is smaller than the current value,
>   excess existing threads will be terminated when they next become idle**.
>   If larger, new threads will, if needed, be started to execute any
>   queued tasks.

So my main problem is: 
How to pause executor to not execute tasks waiting in queue?

Class example definition:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Calc {

    private int numberOfThreads;
    private ThradPoolExecutor pool;
    private Future fut;

    public void setNumberOfThreads(int threads) {
        this.numberOfThreads = threads + 1;
    }

    public void start() {
        if(es == null){
            pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
        } else {
            pool.setCorePoolSize(numberOfThreads);
            pool.setMaximumPoolSize(numberOfThreads);
        }
        fut = pool.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                pool.execute(this::calculate);
            }
        });
    }

    public void suspendCalculations() {
        fut.cancel(true);
    }

    public void continueCalculations() {
        start();
    }

    private void calculate() {
        // calculation logic, not important
    }
}
```

Basing on my example lets imagine situation:

1. call setNumberOfThreads(5)
2. call start()
3. fut will create big queue with tasks waiting to be proceded ex random number 10000
4. call suspendCalculations()
5. call setNumberOfThreads(2)
6. call continueCalculations()

In this way threads cannot be reduced - we got 10000 tasks to be proceded in queue so we need to wait when queue will be empty.

I want to wait until 5 tasks on 5 threads will end and tasks from queue (10000) will be not passed to threads until I call continueCalculations.
In this way I can call setCorePoolSize(2) before continueCalculations because threads will be not processing tasks because of suspendCalculations

Comment: You may wish to consider writing your own `Executor` for this, as there are not any (at least not in core Java) that do this out of the box.

Comment: What is the reason for resizing the thread pool?

Comment: what do you mean by "tasks waiting in queue"?  why at all did you submit that tasks to the executor if you do not want them to run?